# SQL unique index without leading zeros

Tags: sql, mysql

I have set-up a table using the following SQL script:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE ( 
    ID NUMBER NOT NULL, 
    CODE VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT MY_TABLE PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX XUNIQUE_MY_TABLE_CODE ON MY_TABLE (CODE);
```

The problem is that I need to ensure that CODE does not have a leading zero for its value.

How do I accomplish this in SQL so that a 40-char value without a leading zero is stored?

Comment: Do you want to reject values that have leading zero(s), or do you want to strip the leading zero(s) on insert?

Comment: Neither.  I want a 40-char value without a leading zero.

Comment: A 40 character value generation has nothing to do with a unique index - the unique index only validates that the value being added/updated is unique.

Comment: OMG Ponies, sorry the requirement was confusing.  I want to restrict any value that has a leading zero, not generate one.  I have updated the problem description.

Answer (score 1):

`CODE VARCHAR2 NOT NULL CHECK (VALUE not like '0%')`

sorry - slight misread on the original spec

Comment: MySQL has CHECK constraint syntax, but doesn't enforce it on any engine.

Comment: And because of silliness like this, the real WTF in this thread is "MySQL" again.  Friends don't let friends use MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that all `INSERT`s and `UPDATE`s to this table are done through a **stored procedure**, you could put some code there to check that the data is valid and return an error if not.

P.S. A `CHECK CONSTRAINT` would be better, except that MySQL doesn't support them.